# Cloudflare Tunnel without having to also use noTLSVerify?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, cloudflare

I’ve got a simple domain setup on an Ubuntu server running Apache (literally just displays a static HTML file); I set it up with LetsEncrypt and it was working without issue. I wanted a bit more security so decided to use Cloudflare.

I setup the DNS through Cloudflare and it was working flawlessly once I setup the SSL to use the Cloudflare certs (so it would stop the ‘too many redirects error’). This too, worked really well.

Then I read that I could use Tunnels (and then not have to use port forwarding - better security for my home network) so I set up a Cloudflare Tunnel (following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrwoKO7LMzk)

I can make it work if I set this in my `config.yml` file:

```
originRequest:
  noTLSVerify: true
```

I would like to make it work without having to include that snippet - as I would like it to be secure traffic between CF and my Apache server.

My config file is very simple:

```
tunnel: <id>
credentials-file: /route/to/<id>.json

ingress:
  - hostname mydomain.com
    service: https://localhost:443

  - service: http_status404
```

The errors I see in cloudflared service is this:

```
Request failed error="Unable to reach the origin service. The service may be down or it may not be responding to traffic from cloudflared: x509: certificate is valid for *.mydomain.com, mydomain.com, not localhost"
```

What is the best way to avoid using the noTLSVerify in my config but still getting the tunnel to work?

My Apache VirtualHost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
#Old Certs From LE
#SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0001/chain.pem
#SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0001/private_key.pem
SSLCertificateFile /root/.cloudflared/cf_pem.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/.cloudflared/cf_key.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If there is no harm/danger/security risks involved with setting noTLSVerify to true, then I will use it, but otherwise I would prefer not to - just can’t figure out how not to!

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that the LetsEncrypt certificate you have on your machine is for `*.mydomain.com`, but the `cloudflared` daemon is trying to use it to verify the origin at `localhost`. The easiest thing to do here is to add an `originRequest` section into your ingress rule.

e.g.

```
ingress:
  - hostname mydomain.com
    service: https://localhost:443
    originRequest:
        originServerName: mydomain.com
```

This will tell cloudflared's TLS verification algorithm to accept certificates for that domain even though it's connecting to a different one.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/tunnel-guide/local/local-management/ingress/#origin-configuration